# How can I treat food products as unique when my suppliers do not?

Tags: database-design

### Background

I work with a handful of small food manufacturers and store their product information in a database for use in a menu-building application I control. They distribute their product information to me in the form of Excel spreadsheets several times a year.

### Problem

When a food manufacturer changes a product they do not always change the product code.

#### Example

“pea protein” could not be sourced for a product, so it is removed while increasing the quantity of other ingredients. This results in ‘insignificant’ changes in nutrition. In cases like this, it is easier for a food manufacturer to pass the new product as the previous product.

### Goal

When it comes to importing newly distributed product information into my database, I do not want to perpetuate falsehoods by overwriting previous products (identified by the same code) with changes that are deemed insignificant. These changes are often (mathematically) significant to users of the menu builder.

**I want users to know when a product they are using in their menu is not being made any more (i.e. has been delisted) and, *if* there is a new 'version', point them to it.**

How would you suggest I go about this when I cannot uniquely identify products?

Comment: How can you then ?  Surely your answer is in identifying the product and identifying when it changes

Comment: It seems like you need to find a way to uniquely identify product, even if the manufacturer retains the same code, no? Simplest solution seem like it would be just adding new product and updating the old product with link to the newer version.